# Arguments of sh command ignored when using with ssh

Tags: ssh, sh

In the following command, the first argument of *sh* command `echo hey` is ignored:

```sh
$ ssh localhost sh -c 'echo hey; echo ho'

ho
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your commandline is:

```
ssh localhost sh -c 'echo hey; echo ho'
```

`ssh` starts a shell on localhost and passes it the comandline:

```
sh -c echo hey; echo ho
```

The shell on localhost sees two commands. Both run fine.

The problem is that the first command is: `sh -c echo hey`

The option `-c` tells `sh` to execute the next argument. The next argument is `echo`. The extraneous `hey` argument is ignored.

To fix your problem, either change your quoting or just don't run the redundant shell:

```
ssh localhost "sh -c 'echo hey; echo ho'"

ssh localhost 'echo hey; echo ho'
```

The main confusion is probably that `ssh` concatenates all the non-option arguments it receives into a single string that it passes to the remote shell to execute.